# a segmentation fault during a hook

Tags: c, hook

i write a hook.so to hook some syscall of a program , this progrram calls `read` `write` and so on . i use
gnu **arttribute**((constructor)) to noted my init function , this function is :

```c
void get_origin_function() {

  GLIBC_OPEN = (open_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
  GLIBC_OPENAT = (openat_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat");
  LIBC_FOPEN = (fopen_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
  LIBC_FOPEN64 = (fopen64_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen64");
  GLIBC_READ = (read_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
  LIBC_FREAD = (fread_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fread");
  GLIBC_CLOSE = (close_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "close");
  LIBC_FCLOSE = (fclose_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fclose");
  LIBC_FPRINTF = (fprintf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fprintf");
  LIBC_PRINTF = (printf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf");
  GLIBC_WRITE = (write_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

}
```

this function will automitic exec when the hook.so is loaded.
but , when i use `LD_PRELOAD=./hook.so my_program` to test , i get a segmentation fault , i think it is a null ptr reference.

but , when i add `usleep(1)`or`printf("%p %p %p...",GLIBC_OPEN )`.like below ,  the segmentation fault disappeared , i can't figure what happened.

```c
void get_origin_function() {

  GLIBC_OPEN = (open_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
  GLIBC_OPENAT = (openat_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat");
  LIBC_FOPEN = (fopen_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
  LIBC_FOPEN64 = (fopen64_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen64");
  GLIBC_READ = (read_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
  LIBC_FREAD = (fread_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fread");
  GLIBC_CLOSE = (close_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "close");
  LIBC_FCLOSE = (fclose_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fclose");
  LIBC_FPRINTF = (fprintf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fprintf");
  LIBC_PRINTF = (printf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf");
  GLIBC_WRITE = (write_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
  usleep(1); // or printf()

}
```

but when i add the `printf` at the begin of the function like this

```c
void get_origin_function() {
  printf();
  GLIBC_OPEN = (open_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
  GLIBC_OPENAT = (openat_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat");
  LIBC_FOPEN = (fopen_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
  LIBC_FOPEN64 = (fopen64_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen64");
  GLIBC_READ = (read_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
  LIBC_FREAD = (fread_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fread");
  GLIBC_CLOSE = (close_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "close");
  LIBC_FCLOSE = (fclose_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fclose");
  LIBC_FPRINTF = (fprintf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fprintf");
  LIBC_PRINTF = (printf_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf");
  GLIBC_WRITE = (write_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

}
```

i also get segmentation fault , how can this happend0.0

at first i think it might be some of the dynamic library is not loaded in , such as glibc, i try
to add `dlopen` at begin at the function , also failed ..

Comment: *Undefined behavior*, most likely. But with the little code you show it's impossible to say when, where or why. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to show a [mre].

Comment: Please do not write programs that does not check for errors. You have no idea what makes them fail - so a user of such a program is left in total darkness

Comment: sorry , i will make my question more clearly later